# PDF: CalGray to DeviceRGB color space

Tags: pdf, postscript, color-space

I'm using this website http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html to convert CalGray to DeviceRGB color space.

During the conversion there are still some questions...

***Converting CalGray to DeviceRGb takes 3 steps:***

1. Converting CalGray to XYZ values
2. Convert XYZ to linear RGB
3. Companding (compression and expanding)

**Step 1: Convert CalGray to Xs Ys Zs** values using formula Xwhitepoint * Graylevel^Gamma

whitepoint is the white point defined in CalGray and the Xs Ys Zs values are the XYZ values from the source, s.

**Step 2: XYZ to linear RGB**

because the formula from brucelindbloom's website uses transformation matrix [M], I need to calculate this one first.

Can I just use the Xs Ys Zs values from step 1 or should these be first calculated to Xd Yd Zd (d=destination) values using Chromatic adaptation?

Chromatic adaptation see: http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_ChromAdapt.html

Because I need to calculate [M] I need to find the x and y chromaticity values x and y. Therefor go from XYZ to xyY space. S values will also be calculated to use in the matrix.

see: http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html

**Step 3: Companding**

There is Gamma, sRGB and L* companding, which one should be used?

(note: I'm using PDF version 1.3)

Comment: please explain the downvote. If you can't answer the question, don't downvote it.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I do understand why no one has yet answered your question in spite of there being numerous people here who know their way around in PDF. One reason surely is that you have not one but a hand full of questions. I would propose you first concentrate on one issue and ask follow-up questions separately depending on the answers you get to that one.

Comment: well the multiple questions are there because they are related. I thought it was more useful to ask it in one post instead of opening 10 separate questions. Might also be more useful to other readers that are trying to master pdf.

Comment: That might be right. But if I see a question with very many sub-questions, I tell myself to answer not yet but "maybe when I have more time to spare"...

Comment: I'm splitting up the questions: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916893/pdf-what-is-devicergb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device* color spaces are used when you as color data supplier know everything about the device beforehand. So the RIP does not need to perform any conversion on its side. This means you have to use a calibrated color space to perform the conversion. There is no conversion to Device* color space without the device profile.